# Mocking TokenProviders ValidateAsync in identity framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a call in my code that calls the VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync from the UserManager:

```
    public async Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmEmailconfirmationAsync(string token, Account user)
    {
        RegisterTwoFactorProvider(TokenType.Confirmation.ToString(), new TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider<Account, int>());

        if (!await VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, TokenType.Confirmation.ToString(), token))
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed("Invalid code.");
        }

        return await ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, await GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id));
    }
```

I'm trying to mock what this returns and since I can't mock the UserManager class easily I'm trying to mock anything used inside this call.

So far this is the portion of my unit test that is relevent:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ItShouldReturnOk()
    {
        Account = new Account { Id = 1, UserName = "username@email.com", Email = "username@email.com" };

        UserStore.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(1)).ReturnsAsync(Account);
        TokenProvider.Setup(x => x.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<UserManager<Account, int>>(), It.IsAny<CmsAccount>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
        IHttpActionResult result = await AccountController.ConfirmEmail(Model);

        Assert.IsType<OkResult>(result);
    }
```

UserStore and TokenProvider are both mocked. I would have thought these would have covered me but looking at the source code in the identity framework I see where my problem is occurring. Inside the VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync I see this call being made:

```
var result = await _tokenProviders[tokenProvider].ValidateAsync("TwoFactor", token, this, user);
```

It doesn't seem to use a tokenProvider I can mock, unless I am missing out on something. Anyone have any ideas on how to Mock this?

Comment: First thing I did with ASP.NET Identity is to put adapters and wrappers around everything, so I could mock it out. Easier tests would be integration tests for this.

Comment: @RichardMc. Microsoft would have unit tested these frameworks before release. You shouldn't unit test what you don't own. You'd be spending time on something that was already extensively done. Instead, like suggested by CallumLinington, you should abstract that functionality behind types you control and mock/stub/fake these as dependencies for your systems under test.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not make my code hard to maintain, just to add unit tests. Adding Intefaces, dependency injection, and adapters, make the code hard to read and maintain.

I would suggest a shim/fake library, like the one that comes with Visual Studio.  This will allow you to add test code without making your code hard to read.

Benefits of this are things like removing the need to wrap the datetime.now function for tests.

You can simply register a function to be triggered when any code calls datetime.now.

Much cleaner